# Leaflet polyline shifted in IE10 print preview

Tags: printing, svg, internet-explorer-10, leaflet, polyline

I'm using Leaflet 0.6.4 to draw a GPS track. In the print preview using IE10 on Win7, the polyline is badly shifted. The markers are displayed correctly.

To reproduce the problem:

- Use IE 10
- Go to http://en.mycoursewalk.com/course_walk/print/1255
- Right click on the white space and select "Print preview".
- In portrait it looks fine. However, if you select "landscape" the polyline is then shifted almost off the page.

Any ideas what causes this? Other browsers do not have this problem.